# How to add data to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagrid, lambda

I'm having a Structure like

```
 X={ID="1", Name="XX",
    ID="2", Name="YY" };
```

How to dump this data to a `DataGridView` of two columns

The gridView is like

`ID     |  Name`

Can we use LINQ to do this. I'm new to `DataGridView` Pleaese help me to do this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: webforms? winforms? wpf? silverlight?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

first you need to add 2 columns to datagrid. you may do it at design time. see Columns property.
then add rows as much as you need.

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", "XX");
```

Comment: I've added two columns at the design time. now i need to display the data in that `grid view`

Comment: Thank you ... I need to iterate through the structure. So i've to use `for` or `foreach` loop. can we use `LAMBDA` expression for this?

Comment: yes. there are many options. I guess you may use databinding as the best one

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you have a class like this:

```
public class Staff
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And assume you have dragged and dropped a `DataGridView` to your form, and name it dataGridView1.

You need a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) to hold your data to bind your `DataGridView`. This is how you can do it:

```
private void frmDGV_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //dummy data
    List<Staff> lstStaff = new List<Staff>();
    lstStaff.Add(new Staff()
    {
        ID = 1,
        Name = "XX"
    });
    lstStaff.Add(new Staff()
    {
        ID = 2,
        Name = "YY"
    });

    //use binding source to hold dummy data
    BindingSource binding = new BindingSource();
    binding.DataSource = lstStaff;

    //bind datagridview to binding source
    dataGridView1.DataSource = binding;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a binding source.  You can assign the list directly to the grids DataSource.

Comment: Yes we don't need a binding source, we can bind the list to grid's Datasource directly. The advantage of using bindingsource is that we can refresh binding source later if the list has changed/updated. The grid will get the refresh as well.

Comment: Use a System.ComponentModel.BindingList so the list informs the DataGridView that an item was added etc.

Answer (score 3):

My favorite way to do this is with an extension function called 'Map':

```
public static void Map<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> func)
{
    foreach (T i in source)
        func(i);
}
```

Then you can add all the rows like so:

```
X.Map(item => this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(item.ID, item.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is a "query" language (thats the Q), so modifying data is outside its scope.

That said, your `DataGridView` is presumably bound to an `ItemsSource`, perhaps of type `ObservableCollection<T>` or similar. In that case, just do something like `X.ToList().ForEach(yourGridSource.Add)` (this might have to be adapted based on the type of source in your grid).

Answer (score 0):

you shoud do like this form your code

DataGridView.DataSource = yourlist;

DataGridView.DataBind();