# C# I want to add the Value data in datagridview with looping statement

Tags: c#

**hi, I want to add the value data in datagridview of this code;**

```
int tsp;
double mf, tcp, interest, disc;
int a, b;
double MP;

if (comboBox1.Text == "Deferred Cash Payment in 2 years at 0% interest")
{
 a = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
 b = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
 tsp = a * b;

 mf = tsp * 0.07;
 tcp = mf + tsp;
 label8.Text = tcp.ToString("₱000,000.00");

 MP = tcp / 24;
```

**the MP variables has a data; and i want to show it in datagridview with looping statement with 24 rows. and i want the output like this:**

ex.

```
Days  Amount
1     10,000
2     10,000
3     10,000
4     10,000
5     10,000
..
24    10,000
```

Comment: and your question is what?

Comment: not a good idea `if (comboBox1.Text == "Deferred Cash Payment in 2 years at 0% interest")`, better to get the combo index or tag of each row.

Comment: how i can get this
Days  Amount
1     10,000
2     10,000
3     10,000
4     10,000
5     10,000
..
24    10,000

in datagridview

Comment: I think this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923082/how-to-add-data-to-datagridview

Answer (score 0):

In windows forms application you can create a new DataTable instance and bind that DataTable to DataGridView like this;

Your values should appear to your DataGridView. Your changes will be direct to the DataGridView.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Days", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

    dt.Rows.Add(1, 10.00m);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, 10.00m);
    dt.Rows.Add(3, 10.00m);
    dt.Rows.Add(4, 10.00m);
    dt.Rows.Add(5, 10.00m);

    dt.Rows.Add(24, 10.00m);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```